# disable value in s:select

Tags: java, struts

If I have a `Struts` tag like this...

```
<s:select name="country.id" list="countries" listValue="name" listKey="id" headerValue="Select Country" headerKey="" label="Country" />`
```

This is the output code...

```
<select name="country.id" tabindex="12" id="registration_country">
    <option value="">Select Country</option>
    <option value="1">United States</option>
    <option value="2">Afghanistan</option>
    <option value="3">Albania</option>
    <option value="4">Algeria</option>
    ...
    <option value="192">Zambia</option>
    <option value="193">Zimbabwe</option>
</select>
```

What can I do if I want to disable some values, such as options number 1, 3, and 4?

Comment: What do you mean when you say "option number 1, 3, 4 disabled"? I'm not sure you can "disable" a particular option in a select component.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot. Just loop through the collection and set the disabled attribute depending on your criteria.

Answer (score 0):

If you show the options to user, You must let he/she/it to operate.

otherwise, please disable the options or hidden the options.

And you can not "disable" a particular option in a given select component, So it's easy to hidden the options thats no need.